# Android: using pictures in CardView + RecyclerView

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am making a very simple app, testing and learning the `CardView` and the `RecyclerView`. It is just a `CardView` with 1 picture on an `ImageView` and 2 `TextViews`...nothing fancy....just playing around.

I have no problem by the moment, for example I have no `OOM` (it is only 6 or 7 images now), just the emulator is a bit slow.

My question is: the images I am using are random images taken with iphone, with average size of 1.7MB, is that correct?, can you use any image on cardview and recyclerview?. Huge images need any pre-processing to be used in CardView?.

Comment: there's no business with card view ,where never you display huge images, you'd better compress them to prevent OOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if it is a RecyclerView or just a single image view. It is always suggested to compress images while you load them. To start off with you can follow this manual compression approach:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

When you understand the underlying approach you can go ahead with Image libraries like Picasso and Glide.

Comment: thanks, will accept this as an answer due to the link provided

Answer (score 0):

you can not judge what image sizes might be on selection,so use picasso or glide library to show your images(If you are not storing them yourself),this libraries would provide you caching and memory management inbuilt .So basically you will be able to load any image